# javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do a regex where it should alert error msg if the text in the textbox contains the below words.

**Building,apt**
This is the default value in the textbox and the user should enter the building details in that textbox. So if the user submits the form without entering any value in the textbox (then the value of that textbox will be Building,apt by default) then it shuld alert a error msg. I am new to Regex. so I just need to know how to write regex for that??

Comment: This does not require using regular expressions. Just use `===`.

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? As its a constant would `if text == 'Building,apt' not suffice?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: I am using Validationengine.js plugin for validation purpose. I see that they have used regex exp for validation. I am not sure how to implement the above in this plugin. Any ideas would be helpful...

Comment: You could try `/Building,apt/gi`, `/Building,apt/i`, `/Building,apt/` or possibly just `Building,apt` if there are to be no other words

Comment: that didn't work.. I hve given like the below    "match": {
                   "regex": /Building,apt/i,
                    "alertText": "* Please type building or apt details"
                }

Comment: then in the input i hve given the classname 'match'.. But it didnt show any error

Comment: What happens if you just put in `Building,apt`?

Comment: In your input do you have `class=validate[required,custom[match]]`? Do you have this online somewhere that I can look at?

Comment: I have given the input class and regex as above.. but as per the regex it is matching Building,apt... so if the user types anything other than Building,apt, then it would display error msg. what is need is opposite of that?/.. So if there is a value as Building,apt in the textbox then it should display error msg

Comment: let me make it more clear...  "match": {
                   "regex": /^Building,apt/,
                    "alertText": "* Please type building or apt details"
                } and in the html...<input name="addr" type="text" class="finput input_style validate[required,custom[match]] text-input" id="addr" value="Building,apt" onClick="this.value='';"/>

Answer (score 1):

You state that the problem is because you don't want to accept the form field if they leave the default value in place, because the default value is actually just a hint text to show them what to enter.

The correct solution to this is not to have this text as a default value in the field.

In HTML5, there is a new feature called `placeholder`, which allows you to provide this kind of hint text without it being the field value. You use it as an additional attribute in the input element like so:

```
<input name="building" placeholder="Building,apt" value="">
```

This text then appears in the field when the field is unpopulated, but disappears as soon as the user selects the field, and is not actually stored in the field value.

See here for more info: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

For browsers that don't support this feature, you can still code it as per above, but use a JQuery plug-in or other Javascript code to simulate the feature.

Here's a link to one JQuery solution: http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/ but there are plenty of others if you google for them. (as I said, this is only required for browsers that don't support the placeholder feature anyway)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the string equals "Building,apt", the commenters are right; you can just check for equality. When you need to do some more involved pattern matching, you can use the `RegExp` object. Here is more information about it:

[Javascript Regexp](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

If the value you need to check for is the default value, before the user has entered any text then you can use the defaultValue attribute of the text or textarea. If the form element is 
`el` simply do

```
  if (el.value === el.defaultValue) {
     ...
  }
```

No need to repeat the text form the HTML file.